# How to make proper generic harmonization in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's the case:

```
interface IValue {a:string}
interface IFactory<T> { make():T }

class Factory{
    make(): IValue { return {a: 'a'}; }
}

const b = function<T extends IValue>(factory?: IFactory<T>): T {
    return factory.make() || new Factory().make(); // marked as invalid
    // With error:TS2322:Type 'IValue' is not assignable to type 'T'.
};
```

`b` function optionally accepts a value factory or it will be made by default. This is a simplified example of more complex code I have.

I understand that IValue != T (`T` appears as a child of `IValue`), but how should I make harmonization that will expect working not only with children of IValue, but including exact the IValue type itself?

Comment: You code **is** working for `IValue` type itself! Instead it isn't working for any child type.

Comment: Do you need `b` to know about the return type `T`? Right now you can't take that `Factory` and expect it to provide any `T extends IValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the return result to `T` and it will compile.
But there is another bug: if `factory` is invalid, it will cause an error in runtime. I have fixed that. Check the code below.

```
const b = function <T extends IValue>(factory?: IFactory<T>): T {
    //return factory.make() || <T>new Factory().make(); // runtime error
    return <T>(factory || new Factory()).make();
};
```